# CPU / IO intensive async task (mysql database connection failure)

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous

What is the correct way to do this.  Basically this method is combining an IO and CPU intensive task into the same function and running it asynchronously.  Eventually this times out with an exception that it cannot contact the database.  What I think is happening is that due to the large number of threads and when the MySQLConnection (ie conn.Open) is made it is hanging on the internal Mysql.Data code that is waiting for TcpClient.ConnectAsync.Wait(); and eventually times out.  The only way to make this work is to reduce the number of Tasks that are created.

I suspect that waiting for ConnectAsync fails because it can't be granted a thread?

```
public runtest() {
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=***********;port=3306;password=*********"; 
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                //simulate some CPU work
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                conn.Close
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            }
        }));
    }
    var taskarray = tasks.ToArray();
    Task.WhenAll(taskarray).Wait();
}
```

Comment: "I suspect that waiting for ConnectAsync fails because it can't be granted a thread?" Possibly; it takes a while for the .NET Thread Pool to create the 100 threads you will need. It may also be because `MaxPoolSize` in the connection string defaults to 100 and all connections in the pool are busy, so the code is waiting for a connection to be freed up.
Finally note that if you want to do any async DB operations, MySql.Data doesn't support them: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111
Switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to open connection, read/write from/to database, close connection. Then you can do your CPU work, etc. and the DB connection is at that moment already available to something else. Your problem is not in threads, your problem is interleaving of two tasks (DB and computation).

In other words, a database connection is an expensive resource. You are holding this expensive resource while doing something else (other CPU intensive work). That's wrong for all expensive resources.

Btw. your parallel approach is questionable by itself but even with these 100 threads it should be possible to make it work if you implement something like retry of `conn.Open`. If it fails, just retry it after a short while. This "retry" is helpful even in real-world scenarios, because the application can get into problem on network anytime and you can save it with a retry after a few seconds, instead of killing the task completely.